# What is wrong with my VCL (varnish file). I am trying to use a VMOD

Tags: varnish

My VCL :

```
vcl 4.1;
import redis;
import std;
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "2015";
}

sub vcl_init {
    # VMOD configuration: simple case, keeping up to one Redis connection
    # per Varnish worker thread.
    new db = redis.db(
        location="127.0.0.1:6379",
        type=master,
        connection_timeout=500,
        shared_connections=false,
        max_connections=1);
   
    db.command("SET");
    db.push("foo");
    db.push("10s");
    db.execute();
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # Happens before we check if we have this in cache already.
    #
    # Typically you clean up the request here, removing cookies you don't need,
    # rewriting the request, etc
    unset req.http.Cookie;
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
    if ( bereq.url ~ " \.(ts|m3u8)$") {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
        # set beresp.http.cache-control = "public, max-age=259200";
        db.command("GET");
        db.push("foo");
        db.execute(false);
    std.log("HERE" + db.get_string_reply());
    set beresp.ttl = std.duration(db.get_string_reply(), 60s);
    return (pass);
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

I am trying to use a redis vmod.

Problem : As you can see i have put the ttl logic in vcl by using redis.
But whenever i hit the url, varnish always uses default ttl of 120 seconds on the content.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's because the regex itself is wrong. I don't know the reason for that but it makes sense. Varnish defaulted to it's TTL because of the pattern I was hitting there was no handling done in VCL, since what i thought was correct regex was apparently not.

Hence, the default.